# What is "?." operator in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, operator-keyword

I am using a library and in many places ?. 
operator is used i am unable to understand it's purpose.

```
Timer _debounceTimer;
  @override
  initState() {
    _textController.addListener(() {
      // We debounce the listener as sometimes the caret position is updated after the listener
      // this assures us we get an accurate caret position.
      if (_debounceTimer?.isActive ?? false) _debounceTimer.cancel();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> `?.` **[Conditional member access]** - Like `.`, but the leftmost operand can be
>   `null`; example: `foo?.bar` selects property `bar` from expression `foo`
>   unless `foo` is `null` (in which case the value of `foo?.bar` is null)
>
> *from [Dart Language Tour (Other Operators)](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#other-operators)*

TLDR: It is simply does a `null` check before accessing member. If left hand side of the operator is not null then it works simply as `.` and if it is `null` value then the whole thing is `null`.

In your example: `_debounceTimer?.isActive` - if `_debounceTimer` is null then `_debounceTimer?.isActive` <-> `null` and if `_debounceTimer` is not null  then `_debounceTimer?.isActive` <-> `_debounceTimer.isActive`.

Also check: [Dart Language tour (Conditional Expressions)](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions) for `??` and `?` operator.